# C# Delete all checked checkboxes in database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having trouble in deleting the checked checkboxes in the database.
It shows

> > string was not recognized as a valid boolean

on this line:

```
if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
```

This is my code for checkingall checkboxes

```
 if (checkBox2.Checked == false)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
                chk.Value = chk.TrueValue;

            }
        }
        else if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
                chk.Value = 1;

                if (row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    chk.Value = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

//This is my code for deleting checked checkboxes to database.

```
int count = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an item to delete");
        }
        else
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
                {

                    connection.Close();
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = connection;

                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_Archive ([ID],[Date],[StartTime],[EndTime],[NameOfSchool],[Pax],[TourAgency],[Coordinator],[ContactNumber],[Date & Time Added]) VALUES ('"
                    + id + "','" + myDate + "','" + start + "','" + end + "','" + school + "','" + pax + "','" + touragency + "','" + coordinator + "','" + contact + "','" + dateadded + "')";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tbl_Schedule WHERE [ID] = '" + item.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tbl_ScheduledVisitors WHERE [ID] = '" + item.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();

                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Deleted");
            refreshgrid();
            checkBox2.Checked = false;

            //}
        }
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJKoP.png)

Comment: SQL injection anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the following:

```
if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
```

with this:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells[0].Value))
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to diagnose the issue, you can put breakpoints at these two lines:

```
if ((Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true))
```

and

```
if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
```

and see what the value of `item.Cells[0].Value` is.

It's probable that it's not a valid bool string.

Comment: I think the chk.TrueValue doesn't return a true boolean value, it just checks the checkboxes